# is there a way to automatically open a tab when a certain link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

2 links take me to the same page on my website, but I'd like one to open up a tab on that page that wouldn't otherwise be open.

I.E. There are 2 pages; `html1.html` and `html2.html`.

`html1.html` has 2 links that both redirect to `html2.html`; `"link1"` and `"link2"`.

`html2.html` has 2 divs in it; `"content1"` and `"content2"`.

When `"link1"` is clicked the browser will redirect to `html2.html` and I'd like to set `"content1"`'s display to block.

When `"link2"` is clicked the browser will redirect to `html2.html` and I'd like to set `"content2"`'s display to block.

I don't want to have to use a third html document identical to `html2.html` to simulate being on the same page.

Comment: I assume by "*page on my website*" you're meaning a 'portion' of your website with the same URL? It's possible to navigate to a specific page section of a different *file* (`file2.html` from `file1.html` for example), though you cannot alter CSS such as hiding or showing an element this way. You *can*, however, use JavaScript to *simulate* a page change and show new content with changing the URL (which is what I suspect you're doing). In this case, you *can* alter the display of elements based on the click behaviour.

Comment: I did mean a portion of my website with the same URL. Is it possible then to instead of altering the CSS, alter the style with javascript after the link is clicked?

Comment: So basically what you want is show a new div on the same page without page refresh, right?

Comment: @RohanRao Yes, but when you are on a different page, it would redirect AND open up this new div

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple method.

You can set a variable, which will be set to true/false when you click on the link. By using the same variable we can make the Html content hide or visible using condetional statements in javascript.

Comment: You can support your answer by providing a simple example for OP to understand better.

Comment: Is this possible to do without the site being live?